# How to automaticly locate buttons on panel c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a few buttons to add on the form. In the code I'm setting up some button properties:

```
    class DigitButton : Button
{
    private static int digitBtnTag;

    public DigitButton()
        : base()
    {
        this.Size = new Size(30, 30);
        this.Tag = digitBtnTag;
        this.Text = (this.Tag).ToString();
        this.Margin = new Padding(2);
        this.Padding = new Padding(2);
        digitBtnTag++;
    }
}
```

In the MainForm.cs I have

```
 for (int i = 0; i < dgtBtns.Length; i++)
        {
            dgtBtns[i] = new DigitButton();
            dgtBtns[i].Click += new EventHandler(this.digitButtonClick);
            digitPanel.Controls.Add(dgtBtns[i]);                
        }
```

So when I launch a program I see all my buttons in the one place: (0;0) on digitPanel despite property Margin. So why don't all these buttons automaticly "push" each other in the different directions? And how to make it?

Comment: Windows forms does not have the ability to layout dynamically. WPF does and might fit your requirements. FlowLayout panel may work splendidly for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a [FlowLayout Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx) ?

Also, this video might help:
[Windows Forms Controls Lesson 5: How to use the FlowLayout Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb798028.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

that's not the way controls works in c#. i'm guessing you programed at java a bit because the layout in jave works that whay, but in c# just do

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dgtBtns.Length; i++)
    {
        dgtBtns[i] = new DigitButton();
        dgtBtns[i].Location = new Point(50, 50 * i); // Multiplying by i makes the location shift in every loop
        dgtBtns[i].Click += new EventHandler(this.digitButtonClick);
        digitPanel.Controls.Add(dgtBtns[i]);                
    }
```

you'll have to figure out the location parameters by trying and see

Comment: Yeah I tried it and all was perfect, but one guy told me that buttons can be automaticly placed on the form without setting Location property, but setting Margin property

Comment: "that's not the way controls works in _c#_" - a bold statement there sir :D

Comment: @JohnSmith i'll check that, but i haven't heard that one yet

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Left and Top then add the button height or width each time you loop to position your buttons correctly i.e.

```
int bTop=0;
int bLeft=0;

for (int i = 0; i < dgtBtns.Length; i++)
{
    dgtBtns[i] = new DigitButton();
    dgtBtns[i].Click += new EventHandler(this.digitButtonClick);
    dgtBtns[i].Top = bTop;
    bTop += dgtBtns[i].Height;
    digitPanel.Controls.Add(dgtBtns[i]);                
}
```